# How to Host my ASP .NET MVC Application with database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, publish

I really need help or any kind of explanation about my problem.
I have a project built in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. Its a ASP.NET MVC Application, and I have another project which enables me to create a database in my **("localDb")/ProjectsV13**.
My approach was "Database-First", and created `Model.espx` automatically, and everything works fine (Used Entity Framework).

*But now when I'm done making it, I need to PUBLISH It or HOST it. I don't understand the difference between that 2 terms.*
I've been searching for solution for a quite a while, and still no solution.

I need to post in on CPanel.
How can someone use my app online?
**How can someone see the same data as me?**. Because I use  `localDb`.

For example, I  have login page for admin (just want someone to login with username:"Admin" and pw: "admin") and use my app.
I published it using FileSystem and managed to start my app with localhost. But that's not what I need

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How you deploy your website completely depends on the web hosting service you're using, such as IIS, TomCat, Apache, Xampp to name a few. As for the database, you'll need to ensure you install the localdb service on your remote host, first. How you do this depends on your service provider.

Comment: Does it have to be CPanel? You might find it easier to publish a .Net + SQL Server web app straight to Azure. I looked for some CPanel guides and I couldn't find any that looked up to date, it seems like an out of date solution to me.

Comment: This is an example of a guide to publish asp.net + MS SQL to Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase, although this is code first, not db first

Comment: Basically if you are using Windows, then hosting provider use Plesk ask their control panel. If you are using Plesk, then you can just read this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-using-web-deploy-with-plesk-control-panel/ about how to publish your .net core website.

Comment: Yes,it has to be CPanel, i mean they gave acc on it, and expect me to send them my app so they can test it. 
If i use Azure,is that free? i saw many tutorials for it.. 
When i build my solution i get Bin and obj file,those 2 files i should upload right? with all DLL-s

Comment: @MareZen Yes, Azure is free, but it is limited. If you are using SQL server, then you need to check their calculator pricing first since Azure is very expensive if you are using SQL. Azure is cloud service, it doesn't comes with Cpanel. It is easy to use but you must be careful with their price. If you're looking for Control panel, then you can use shared hosting, I would recommend Asphostportal for .net and SQL server hosting.

Comment: @TheGunners Thank you , i got permission, to change platform. I can now try to deploy my app to Azure. Is there any good tutorial sites for it? Is it complicated to publish it?

Comment: @MareZen If you are using Azure, read this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/

Comment: @TheGunners Thank you so much! By the way.. i bought domain on AspHostPortal , "Host One" package,or w-e.. It says it has support for .NET,well for my app, and SQL server and db. When i want to publish now my app,i should create db on server and upload only "bin" file right? or is there any other step i missed? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MareZen Create the db via their control panel, then you can upload your .bak file to them for restoration. I believe you can contact their support team if you have issues.